# Using Javascript library from other project

Tags: javascript, asp.net, resources, virtualpathprovider

I have two websites and in one of them I have some scripts that I want to use on the second website, I don't want to copy the .js files to the other projects, because if I had some change on the .js file I will have to do the same thing twice.

I don't know how can I do it, I've already read something abou Virtual Path Provider, but it apparently doesn't work fine for me, the .js files are in sub-folders, and the VPP won't find it.

Could someone give me ideas about what I should do?

Comment: Can you not load it using a script tag in the normal way?

Comment: Store it somewhere with a publicly accessible URL and use `script` tags.  Don't adopt complex solutions to simple problems.